# JSP Checkbox multiple informations

Tags: javascript, html

I have this checkboxs form:

```
<form action = "main.jsp" method = "POST" target = "_blank">
       FIT <input type = "checkbox" name = "collage" value="FIT"/><br>
       FDU <input type = "checkbox" name = "collage" value="FDU"/><br> 
       FAM <input type = "checkbox" name = "collage" value="FAM"/><br> 
</form
```

and this .jsp to print what user check:

```
<%
    String[] exp = request.getParameterValues("college");
    for (String tempExp : exp) {
        out.println("<li>" + tempExp + "</li>");
     }
%>
```

What I want to do is that when user check on box, program print him hyperlink to for example google. Lets say at index.html home page, user press FIT and FDU check box program need to print him at new page:
You pressed "FIT" --- hyperlink to google.
You pressed "FDU" --- hyperlink to google.

I dont know how to do this because I just go thorught this loop and print what user check but cant print info about that checkbox.

Comment: You do not need a JSP for this. You can do it in HTML file using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use data-attributes to store data, this allows the code to be simple and reusable.

This was done client side, no need for server side programming.

```js
var _checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]");
var _results = document.querySelector("#results");

_checkboxes.forEach(function(el){
      el.addEventListener("change",function(){
        if(el.checked){
            var _url = el.getAttribute("data-url");
            _results.innerHTML += "You clicked on " + _url + "<br>";
        }
      });
});
```

```html
<form>
       FIT <input data-url="https://google.com" type = "checkbox" name = "collage" value="FIT"/><br>
       FDU <input data-url="https://google2.com" type = "checkbox" name = "collage" value="FDU"/><br> 
       FAM <input data-url="https://google3.com" type = "checkbox" name = "collage" value="FAM"/><br> 
</form>
<div id="results"></div>
```